# Display inline-block elements in variable-width div with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I am having the following layout:

https://jsfiddle.net/0r6cdwht/2/

How is it possible to achieve a horizontal scroll in this particular case if displayed items within the div are overflowing?

I've looked into this and one answer I found was to use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

on the container div, but in my case this would scroll all page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are positioning the element `200px` to the left, you could use [`calc(100% - 200px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate the `max-width` of the element. Then add `overflow: auto` and `white-space: nowrap` to conditionally add the scrollbar depending on the number of children items:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/wccdfyhk/)

```
.devices {
    max-width: calc(100% - 200px);
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:auto;` will work inside the class. But without a defined width inside the DIV you won't see it.

Does that make sense?

I added overflow:auto; to your fiddle but it didn't work until after I removed spaces from random text.